# Eslint indent with chained methods

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, eslint, chained

How do I configure eslint to:

```
Promise.all(promises)
.then(() => {
  myExampleFunction()
})
```

instead of:

```
Promise.all(promises)
    .then(() => {
      myExampleFunction()
    })
```

We are using the following eslint packages:

```
"eslint": "4.12.0",
"eslint-plugin-promise": "3.6.0",
"eslint-plugin-react": "7.5.1",
"eslint-plugin-react-native": "3.2.0",
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can set MemberExpression to 0 as per documentation

"Indent of 2 spaces with MemberExpression set to 0 will indent the multi-line property chains with 0 spaces." - [indent - Rules](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/indent#memberexpression)

as inline comment
`/*eslint indent: ["error", 2, { "MemberExpression": 0 }]*/`

in .eslintrc
`"rules": {"indent": ["error", 2, { "MemberExpression": 0 }]}`